# Listar datos de una tabla EF-NET CORE 2.1 desde el modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Perdón si la pregunta es muy larga pero quise detallar lo que hice con el fin de guiarme y encontrar que hice mal. Trabajando con MVC (no CORE), yo añadia mi base de datos usando el "ayudante de EF" (no se como se llama "ADO.net Entity Data Model template") a mi proyecto, la cuestión es que me quedaba el archivo de `Context` y el de `X tabla` asi:

**Context** (falta mas pero solo quise agregar digamos lo revelante para mi)

```
public partial class ACME : DbContext
{
  public ACME()
    : base("name=ACME1")
    {
    }

  public virtual DbSet<clientes> clientes { get; set; }
```

**cliente.cs**

```
public partial class clientes
    {
        [Key]
        public int id_Empresa { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string nombreEmpresa { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string admiEmpresa { get; set; }
```

La cuestión es que yo siempre desde mi modelo (osea los archivos con los nombres de las tablas de mi base de datos) hago los CRUD (listado, actualizacion, borrado, etc)

Por ejemplo si quiero listar los clientes lo haria desde el archivo `clientes.cs`de esta manera:

```
//LISTA LOS CLIENTES
public List<clientes> listar()
{
   var listaCliente = new List<clientes>();

   using (var ctx = new ACME())
   {
     listaCliente=ctx.clientes.ToList();
   }

     return listaCliente;
}
```

El problema de mi consulta viene con NET CORE 2.1, estoy creando la base de datos con EF manualmente (sin la ayuda del template), lo cual me queda los 2 archivos asi:

**ModelContext**

```
namespace EjemploCRUD.Model
{
    public class ModelContext : DbContext
    {
        public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Libros> libro { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Libros.cs**

```
namespace EjemploCRUD.Model
{
    public class Libros
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Usando la logica del ejemplo anterior quise listar los elementos de la tabla agregando este codigo:

```
public List<Libros> listado()
 {
    var lista = new List<Libros>();

    using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
    {
       ctx.libro.ToList();
    }

     return lista;
 }
```

Me salta un error en la la linea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal
>   requerido 'options' de
>   'ModelContext.ModelContext(DbContextOptions)'

Según me esta faltando un argumento pero no se cual es, lo cual añado la recomendacion que me da el visual y se añade una mas codigo al archivo `ModelContext`:

```
public ModelContext()
{
}
```

A la hora de ejecutar la pagina me lanza este error:

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: 'No database provider has been
>   configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by
>   overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext
>   on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then
>   also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a
>   DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to
>   the base constructor for DbContext.'

Ahora mi consulta, a que se deben los 2 errores (aunque siento que el principal es el primero) y porque no puedo listar los elementos de la tabla como en MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que, como solo utilizas el constructor `public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options) : base(options)` debes crear un objeto del tipo `DbContextOptions<ModelContext>` para poder usar el ModelContext por ejemplo

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptions<ModelContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Cadena de coneccion");
using (var context = new ModelContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
  // tu código aqui
}
```

El segundo error cuando agregas el constructo vacío hace referencia a que necesitas especificar un proveedor de Entity Framework Core. Una forma de solucionarles es agregar código al constructor para especificar el provedor. Otra forma de solucionarlo es sobre escribiento el método `OnConfiguring` por ejemplo agregando el metodo a tu ModelContext

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("tu cadena");
}
```

La documentación lo explica muy bien: [Configurar un DbContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)

Answer (score 1):

Si estas en `asp.net core` tienes que definir el `services.AddDbContext()` en `ConfigureServices` de `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //resto codigo

    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

}
```

es alli donde defines el `DbContext` y las `options`

Al usa `options.UseSqlServer()` estas indicando el provider que indica el mensaje que recibes

[Introducción a EF Core en ASP.NET Core con una base de datos nueva](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, de hecho esta conexión la tengo, puedo acceder a la base de datos y traer datos, CRUD, etc, pero mi consulta es que como puedo acceder digamos "a la lista" de datos desde el model (como el ejemplo que puse de MVC) y no desde el controlador/PageModel.

Saludos.